# Java polymorphism: Why is an error returned?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why does running

```
Larry var3 = new Jerry();
var3.method3();
```

output an error instead of

> larry 1
>
> harry 1
>
> mary 3

I think it might have something to do with the way the object was created. But it's just my speculation.

This is the code:

```
public class Harry {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("harry 1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        method1();
        System.out.println("harry 2");
    }
}

public class Larry extends Harry {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("larry 1");
        super.method1();
    }
}

public class Mary extends Larry {
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("mary 2");
    }

    public void method3() {
        super.method1();
        System.out.println("mary 3");
    }
}

public class Jerry extends Mary {
    public void method2() {
        super.method2();
        System.out.println("jerry 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error?  That's always important.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's an online assignment on Practice-it. You either indicate the output of the code or type in "error" if otherwise. With the method stated above, error is the correct answer.

Comment: Then you should paste the code into a real environment, even an online compiler and run it. You can't expect to be able to properly debug your code for errors when you don't even know what the error is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm a beginner in Java, I just started Polymorphism chapter a few days ago. I just need to know why the method couldn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Larry var3 = new Jerry(); // casting Jerry to Larry. 
var3.method3(); // there is no Larry.method3 method.
// You need downcast object to derived class with method3() defined to call it
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
((Mary) var3).method3();
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was asking why the method doesn't run with the created object.